# Use Magento 2 in production

Tags: production, magento2

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

i want to use a multiple store infra structure and i decided to use Magento. i looked for a composer installation and i found one. So i installed Magento. the problem is that i used Magento 2 in version 0.74.0-beta16.

My question: Can use this version for production instead of Magento 1. The release plan (http://www.mag-tutorials.de/magento-2-release-plan/) says, that at the beginning 2016 Magento 2 to will be officially release. And the functionality is tested by Unit Tests, so the already existing functionality must be guranteed expect some special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Magento 2 in production at this time because payment doesn't work. The release is scheduled for November and you should be able to use it then.